# On the truncation of spherical harmonics

Tags: signal-processing, data-analysis, spherical-harmonics

Suppose there is a function $f(\theta,\phi)$ defined on the surface of a sphere, and $\theta$ and $\phi$ are the polar and azimuthal angles respectively. Similar with the fact that a function defined on a line or a circle can be expanded with respect to the Fourier bases, this function $f$ can be expanded in terms of the spherical harmonics $Y_l^m(\theta, \phi)$:
$$f(\theta,\phi)=\sum_{l=0}^{\infty} \sum_{m=-l}^l F_l^m Y_l^m(\theta,\phi),$$
where $l$ and $m$ are the degree and order of the harmonics. In order for the expansion to achieve a perfect fitting to the original function, $l$ needs to go from 0 to $\infty$.

In our experiment design, however, we cannot detect directly the value of the original function but can only detect the expansion coefficients $F_l^m$, and unfortunately, the orders of $F_l^m$ we are able to detect is limited, ie. $l \leq l_0$, so in fact we are using a truncated summation $$\sum_{l=0}^{l_0} \sum_{m=-l}^l F_l^m Y_l^m(\theta,\phi)$$ to simulate the original function. When $l_0$ is small, even though the truncated function captures the overall variation trends of the original function well, the amplitudes are significantly different from the originals.

So my question is: is there a way to mathematically scale the truncated function value to a direct comparable level with the original function? If so, how to do it please? Any input would be greatly appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If the amplitude differs significantly from the original, then the $L^2$ difference between your reconstructed signal and the original is large, then there is a lot of higher frequency information missing. So I cannot believe that you have the overall variation trends captured.

Comment: If you are working with crystalline fields, the expansion is usually truncated by selection rules.

Comment: @WillieWong, Yes there is a lot of high frequency information missing, you're right. But the amplitudes of these high frequency terms are also smaller compared to the lower degree ones, so it can still show the overall map. It like drawing a portrait, we cannot capture the details like the eyes, nose, or the mouth, but we can have a rough idea of where the face is, the belly is, the legs are, and to us this rough information in this experiment is also important.

Comment: @FelixMarin, yes I am working with crystalline fields. Could you be more specific on the selection rules please? So the convention in this field is to truncate the term up to 16th or 32nd order, and that will give you a set of amplitudes on the sphere; if we can only get the terms up to, say, 6th or 8th, but based on this information we want to have a rough guess of the max and min value of the function should be if truncated up to 16th degree, would it be possible? Thanks.

Comment: @Lampard: to your final question in your previous comment: no. The whole point of the spherical harmonic expansion is that the different harmonics are independent of each other, and so given an arbitrary signal information up through the 8th order will give you absolutely zero information about the 9th through 16th order. An _arbitrary_ signal can easily have the first 8 orders being identically zero and the 10th order being rather large. On the other hand, if your data is coming from a physical experiment, the physical laws often dictate that there can be some correlation between modes.

Comment: (So in other words your signal is not truly "arbitrary".) But you will need to tell us what the set-up is and preferably what are the known correlation for the question to be answerable. On the other hand, I suspect as @FelixMarin said, much of these is classical and are already captured in the truncation "by selection rules". And quite likely you cannot beat _that_ (in the sense that if you truncate even more you start to lose information that cannot be recovered).

Comment: ${\rm f}\left(\theta,\phi\right)$ will involve integrals of three Spherical Harmonics once you take into account the crystalline field. Something like $\int{\rm Y}_{\ell_{1}m_{1}}^{*}\left(\Omega\right){\rm Y}_{\ell m}\left(\Omega\right){\rm Y}_{\ell_{2}m_{2}}\left(\Omega\right)\,{\rm d}\Omega$. That yields selection rules that "truncates" the expansion. Sometimes, we just need to know the crystalline field symmetries.

Comment: @WillieWong, thank you so much for your input on the issue, really appreciate it. I'll go more details on the setup of our physical problem: suppose $f(\theta,\phi)$ is a probability function defined on the surface of the sphere which satisfies $$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^\pi f(\theta,\phi) \sin\phi d\phi d\theta =1.$$If we consider the maximum value $f$ can reach, two occasions should set the lower and upper bound respectively: 1. $f=1/4\pi$ everywhere, 2. $f$ is a Dirac impulse somewhere and equal to 0 anywhere else. Any other instances will definitely generate values in between these two.

Comment: @FelixMarin, same gratitude to you too. Now continue previous comment. If truncate $F_l^m$ for cases 1, no error at all because only $F_0^0 \neq 0$, and still $f=1/4\pi$ everywhere; for case 2 the truncation to 6th degree cause the reconstructed $f$ to have smaller and oscillatory amplitudes compared to those truncated to 22th degree, for example, the latter may get a value of 30 at impulse position and the former may only get 6. Now if max value of $f_1$ truncated to 6th degree lie between, say,  =4.5, could we infer that if $f_1$ truncated to 22th degree, the value should approx be, say, 20?